# What is the Sunnah method to clean the finger after finishing the meal?

Tags: sharia, sunnah, food

What should be the way to clean finger after meal,Is it good manner to clean finger in plate after meal?

Comment: As opposed to washing under a tap or a finger bowl?

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

As you have asked about cleaning the fingers in plate after finishing the meal so the preferred and Sunnah method is to lick the fingers after finishing the food.It is one of the beneficial sunnah (Medically healthy too) which which has been forgotten  nowadays and need to get revived.

> Ka'b bin Malik (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: I saw
> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) eating with three fingers (i.e., the thumb, the
> index finger and the middle finger) and licking them after having
> finished the food. [[Muslim]](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:748).
>
> Ibn Ka'b b. Malik reported on the authority of his father that he saw
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) licking his three fingers (after having finished
> the food). Ibn Hatim made no mention of" three".(Muslim)

Similarly in some Ahadith it is stated not to wipe the hands unless it is licked to acheive the full blessings

> It was narrated from Jabir that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: “None
> of you should wipe his hand until he has licked it, for he does not
> know where the blessing if in his food.’”([Ibn Majah](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1273780))
>
> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying: When any one of
> you eats food he should lick his fingers, for he does not know in what
> part of the food sticking to his fingers the blessing lies.(Muslim)
>
> It was narrated from Ibn ‘Abbas that the Prophet (ﷺ) said: “When one
> of you eats food, let him not wipe his hand until he has licked it or
> has someone else to lick it.”(ibn Majah)

Rasulullah Salallahu alayhi wasallam has emphasized to finish the food properly with licking the fingers without wasting and not to leave some part for Shaytan but our scholars have mentioned to avoid licking the fingers during the meal so it should be done after finishing and before wiping the hands.

> Jabir reported: I heard Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) as saying: The Satan is
> present with any one of you in everything he does; he is present even
> when he eats food; so if any one of you drops a mouthful he should
> remove away anything filthy on it and eat it and not leave for the
> devil; and when he finishes (food) he should lick his fingers, for he
> does not know in what portion of his food the blessing lies.(Muslim)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.